# Why isn't my function sorting object properties correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I am making a react table with sortable columns. When I sort the age row, the result is not sorted properly. I went and checked back to make sure I was sorting properly and added some repeat numbers to the data. I also checked for white space or errors in the data. I also tried making sure they were numbers and not strings. There doesnt seem to be anything wrong with any of the "age" properties. So why is sort regarding 25 as higher than 32?

Here is the code (I trimmed out the repetetive other properties, annotated by the ..., except for the spread operator, thats a spread operator of course):

```
function PeopleList({participants}){
    const [reverse, setReverse] = useToggle(true);
    let [sortType, setSort] = useState('default')

    let reverseFunction = (arr) => {
        if(reverse){
            return arr.reverse()
        } else {
            return arr
        }
    }

let sortRows = {
...
        age: {
            class: 'age',
            fn: (a, b) => a-b
        },
        default: {
            class: 'default',
            fn: (a, b)=>a
        }
     }
return (
      <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
...
                <td><Button onClick={()=>{setSort('age'); setReverse()}}>
...
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
{reverseFunction([...list].sort(sortRows[sortType].fn)).map(person=>{
            return <tr>
...
                    <td>{person.age}</td>
...
                   </tr>
)}
)}
```

And here is a screenshot of the resulting sort:
[image]

Comment: What  is the value of `sortType` in tbody?

Comment: The button sets it to age, but it starts out as default. The issue was that I was sorting the objects instead of the property.

Comment: Are the numbers being entered as a string and not an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed the error just as I was about to submit the question. Since I edited the question carefully I thought I would submit in case it's of use to anyone overlooking the same error as well.

I was sorting the objects, instead of the object properties. To sort by age properly the parameter's age properties should be compared.

```
       age: {
            class: 'age',
            fn: (a, b) => a.age-b.age //Remember the property
        },
```

Comment: I can imagine that this is an unnecessarily complex example of the error and am willing to take it down if it is found to contribute more to bloat than anything.